# Why can't I access /tmp after my execve(/bin/sh) exploit?

Tags: privilege-escalation

I succesfully tried to exploit an old version of Apache. A shell is spawned with user www-data (id=33), but I can't "ls" or "cat" anything in /tmp. I can ls the contentns of /bin instead, for example.
I even added a file in /tmp and changed its owner to ww-data but still can't "cat" in the exploit shell.
Why is that ? Is there some permission system I don't understand ? Note that /tmp is world readable.

Comment: What do you mean by "you can't"? Do you get an error? Which one?

Comment: Yes, please explain in detail what happens when you try. It's definitely possible that the www-data user is prohibited from reading that directory or its contents - this is doable with classic Unix permissions, and easy with ACLs - but you'd need to provide more info for us to tell if that's what's happening.

Comment: I do not get an error, but the output of ls /tmp is empty. Yet the command works with other unpriviledg users in a normal terminal (I put a few files in /tmp). I changed ownership of one of these files ("/tmp/foo") to www-data but "cat" won't work I get : 'cat: /tmp/foo: No such file or directory\n'

Comment: I have added www-data to sudoers, yet sudo ls outputs nothing in tmp (but works in other dirs including the root). What am I msising ?

Comment: There's not enough here to help you. There are simply too many possible reasons that you need to start troubleshooting. And this is not looking like a security question.

Comment: @schroeder I have to disagree with the claim it's not a security question, since I am precisely wondering which security mechanism is used here, since it's not classic unix permissions.

Comment: You aren't even clear that it is a permission issue, though. And Unix permission issues belong on a Unix site.